# Use of the indefinite article before a noun and a number

Tags: articles, indefinite-article

Tell me please why *an* was used before the word *option* in the following sentence.

> Two - we collapse miserably into ruins and ashes. I don't like "two", Stan, is there (**an**) option three?

I thought that when there is a number after a noun then articles are not used. For example:

> Read chapter one to get more information!
>
> He is now in room five.

I am very confused why *an* was used there.

Comment: Here *an* functions as a cardinal number.

Comment: Think of it as a shortened version of "Is there an option (labelled) 'three'?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Stan, is there (an) option three?

This is equivalent to

> Is there a 3rd option?

using a cardinal number after a noun often works similar to an ordinal number; e.g. "Chapter One" is the first chapter.

"Option three" thus refers to a (potential) option, which would be numbered three if they were in order.

> Two - we collapse miserably into ruins and ashes. I don't like "two"

In this part, the "two" likely refers to "option two" (and presumably there was previously mentioned an option one).

The indefinite article is used because the person asking Stan in unsure whether there is another option (i.e. are options one and two the only possibilities?).